# XML Serialization with long xmls

Tags: android, xml, serialization

I'm working on a game of test and different questions. The user can select a topic from a menu and in each menu there are 20-30 questions. What I want to do is to serialize my code into XML in order to write a XML file when the user clicks the finish button. (considering he could do 1 , 2 or 10 test). I've been testing this with a simple XML but I don't know if this is the best solution.

Here is the format of the exported file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RESPUESTAS ID_CONVOCATORIA="21044826">
 <INCIDENCIA />
<NUM_PDA>PDA600035&#x0;</NUM_PDA>
<TEST Nom_Test="A_VER_SUP_01">
<NUM_TEST>1</NUM_TEST>
<NUMERO_ITEMS>19</NUMERO_ITEMS>
<CARACTERISTICAS VARIAS_RESPUESTAS="NO" HIPSATIVO="NO" />
<TIEMPO_TEST TIEMPO_TEST="SI">
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TEST>900</VALOR_TIEMPO_TEST>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO>900</VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO>
</TIEMPO_TEST>
<TIEMPO_ITEM TIEMPO_ITEM="NO" />
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="1">
  <RESPUESTA>D</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="2">
  <RESPUESTA>D</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="3">
  <RESPUESTA>B</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="4">
  <RESPUESTA>D</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="5">
  <RESPUESTA>D</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="6">
  <RESPUESTA>B</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="7">
  <RESPUESTA>B</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="8">
  <RESPUESTA>A</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="9">
  <RESPUESTA>D</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="10">
  <RESPUESTA>D</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="11">
  <RESPUESTA>B</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="12">
  <RESPUESTA>D</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="13">
  <RESPUESTA>C</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="14">
  <RESPUESTA>D</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="15">
  <RESPUESTA>A</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="16">
  <RESPUESTA>C</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="17">
  <RESPUESTA>C</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="18">
  <RESPUESTA>A</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="19">
  <RESPUESTA>
  </RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
 </ITEM>
 </TEST>
 <TEST Nom_Test="A_NUM_SUP_01">
<NUM_TEST>2</NUM_TEST>
<NUMERO_ITEMS>15</NUMERO_ITEMS>
<CARACTERISTICAS VARIAS_RESPUESTAS="NO" HIPSATIVO="NO" />
<TIEMPO_TEST TIEMPO_TEST="SI">
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TEST>1020</VALOR_TIEMPO_TEST>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO>1020</VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO>
</TIEMPO_TEST>
<TIEMPO_ITEM TIEMPO_ITEM="NO" />
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="1">
  <RESPUESTA>B</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="2">
  <RESPUESTA>B</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="3">
  <RESPUESTA>C</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="4">
  <RESPUESTA>A</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="5">
  <RESPUESTA>A</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="6">
  <RESPUESTA>A</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="7">
  <RESPUESTA />
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="8">
  <RESPUESTA>C</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="9">
  <RESPUESTA>B</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="10">
  <RESPUESTA>C</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="11">
  <RESPUESTA>D</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="12">
  <RESPUESTA>A</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="13">
  <RESPUESTA>D</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="14">
  <RESPUESTA>A</RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
<ITEM NUM_ITEM="15">
  <RESPUESTA>
  </RESPUESTA>
  <VALOR_TIEMPO_TRANSCURRIDO />
</ITEM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` seems to be what you need.

That's what my solution looks like. I have written this helper class:

```
public class XmlHelper {
    private static String NS_EMPTY = "";

    private XmlSerializer mSerializer;
    private StringWriter mWriter;
    private String mRootTag;

    public void start(String rootTag) throws IOException {
        mSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        mWriter = new StringWriter();
        mRootTag = rootTag;

        mSerializer.setOutput(mWriter);
        mSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        mSerializer.startTag(NS_EMPTY, mRootTag);
    }

    public void addText(String tag, String text) throws IOException {
        mSerializer.startTag(NS_EMPTY, tag);
        mSerializer.text(text);
        mSerializer.endTag(NS_EMPTY, tag);
    }

    public void addTextIfNotEmpty(String tag, String text) throws IOException {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            addText(tag, text);
        }
    }

    public void addText(String tag, int number) throws IOException {
        addText(tag, String.valueOf(number));
    }

    public void startTag(String tag) throws IOException {
        mSerializer.startTag(NS_EMPTY, tag);
    }

    public void endTag(String tag) throws IOException {
        mSerializer.endTag(NS_EMPTY, tag);
    }

    public void finish() throws IOException {
        mSerializer.endTag(NS_EMPTY, mRootTag);
        mSerializer.endDocument();
    }

    public String render() {
        return mWriter.toString();
    }
}
```

Then serialization looks something like this:

```
XmlHelper xmlHelper = new XmlHelper();

xmlHelper.start("request");
xmlHelper.addText("action", "add");
xmlHelper.startTag("person");
xmlHelper.addText("first_name", t.getFirstName());
xmlHelper.addText("last_name", t.getLastName());
xmlHelper.endTag("person");

xmlHelper.finish();
```

(it is just an example, you should use your own scheme)

And you should complete XmlHelper class to add attributes support (see `XmlSerializer` documentation)

Comment: I will check XML Serializer, thank your for your help and examples